# How to find first day of the month with DateTime class

Tags: php, datetime

I'm making a calendar but I ran into a problem.
I have been trying to find out how to get the first day of a month.
I used to do it like this:

```
$start = date('d', strtotime("$year-$month-1")); // For this month '2015-9' it returns 1
```

Now I know I need to add 1 empty element in the calendar to start at the correct day.

But now I would like to do this with the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class but I have no idea of how to do this. I would like to know if something similar to the above code is doable with the DateTime class.

**Update**

Lets asume That my calendar is below.

```
|S|M|T|W|T|F|S|
|0|1|2|3|4|5|6|
```

Each month starts on a different day and I would like to know this days number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the first day of any given month is always numbered **1**.. But assuming you want other properties of this month as well; you can use:

```
$date = new DateTime('2010-09-21');
$date->modify('first day of this month');
echo $date->format('r');
```

After your update; my answer needs only a small tweak; output `$date->format('N');` to get the day-of-the-week number. An overview of the formats you can use is [in the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: Maybe my update makes more sense

Comment: Updated my answer accordingly